# display a dialog window for each element of table when clicking on a button in twig view

Tags: javascript, html, symfony, loops, twig

I have this code in my **twig** view for my **symfony** project:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>DATA 1</th>
      <th>DATA 2</th>
      <th>DATA 3</th>
      <th>DATA 4</th>
      <th>DATA 5</th>
      <th>DATA 6</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for currentData in arrayData %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ currentData.data1}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.data2}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.data3}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.data4}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.data5}}</td>
        <td>{{ currentData.data6}}</td>
        <td>
          <a><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="show">Show Details</button></a> <!-- for open dialog window -->
          <a href="{{ path('editData', {'idData': currentData.idData }) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Edit</button></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- dialog window-->
<dialog id="window">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a>Detail</a>
        </li>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right" id="exit">Close</button>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body page-header">
    <!-- my content here -->
  </div>
</dialog>

<script>
  (function() {
    var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
    document.getElementById('show').onclick = function() {
      dialog.show();
    };
    document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
      dialog.close();
    };
  })();
</script>
```

As you can see, it's a basic html page. I display all my **datas** in a table in my **loop** `{% for currentData in arrayData %}`. 
On this table, there are two types of button: `Show Details` button and `Edit` button. The Edit button works well, there's no problem, my redirection works for all datas in my table and I can edit data I chose.

For the button `Show Details`: the desired behavior is that a **window dialog** opens in my page and contains every datas I need to display **for each lines**. But in fact, my dialog window works just on the first line of my table when clicking on `Show Details`, and when I click on another Show Details button of another line, nothing happened (really nothing).

Where am I wrong?

*Note that for now, I don't pass datas in my window dialog, I make it through Ajax and Symfony Controller.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `id` is used to get a single dom element, and you shouldn't use same `id` on multiple dom elements, what you should do is add a class like `show` :
`<a><button class="btn btn-info btn-xs show" id="show">Show Details</button></a>`, then use  `document.getElementsByClassName('show')` to get all the button that has the class `show`, then you can addEventlistener to each of them:

```
(function() {
    var dialog = document.getElementById('window');
    // Array of the buttons.
    var showButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('show');
    // Event handler
    var showDialog = function() {
      // Now you have to use the show button as base , to find the data you want
      // to display...
      console.log(this);
      dialog.show();
    };
    var i, len = showButtons.length;
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        showButtons[i].onclick = showDialog;
    }
    document.getElementById('exit').onclick = function() {
      dialog.close();
    };
  })();
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rty0hktr/1/)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understand that I have not to select the id in thiese condition for valid HTML. I like the way you explain and comment your code, it allows me to really understand javascript in this way of coding. That's why I choose your answer.

Comment: Thanks, you just encouraged me to keep this coding style when answering questions on SO!

Comment: You are welcome, and sincerely, this way of sharing the comprehension of code is a best way to understand mistakes and to have appropriate behavior when writing code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this line in the body of a loop:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="show">
```

This will result in the `id` attribute not being unique – which is not valid and which will not work. You could append `{{ loop.index }}` to the current `id` value to generate unique IDs, or (better) use jQuery and do something like ...

```
$('button.btn.btn-info.btn-xs').on(
    'click',
    function() {
        var clickedButton = $(this);
        // do something ...
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I understand the mistake I have done, not selected an id if I make a loop on.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to set the same id to all of your buttons. Don't do that - it's not valid HTML. You should use a class instead and grab ALL of your buttons with getElementsByClassName, like this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("show"); 

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
        alert("Why hello there!");
    };
}
```

Here's an example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0qaht3ry/

Comment: Sorry by my rookie mistake, I understand where is the problem by selecting the id in this way with my twig loop. Thank you, and happy coding.